# Adding An id dynamically to WordPress generated divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a wordpress website I am working on using Advanced Custom Fields. Right now I have it dynamically generating divs on a page, would like to do is insert a unique id to each div that currently has the id="fader" and ad a unique id to each div with the class="headerBanner".

I have tried a few different methods and none work

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="headerBanner"><img src="http://dev.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Exterior-Constuction_Parallax-1.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper-body innerPage">
  <div class="wrap clearfix">
    <div class="col-row clearfix markets" id="fader">
      <div class="col two txtpg">
        <div class="col">
          <h3>Siding</h3>
          <p>Client Name has long been recognized as an industry leader in the siding and vertical cladding market.</p>
          <p>Siding has a solid place in the residential housing market as an aesthetically pleasing and cost-effective solution to protect the house from the elements. Client Name has been at the technological forefront to help siding producers keep &#8211; and grow &#8211; their market share.</p><a class="moreBtn" href="/markets/exterior-construction-outdoor-durable-products/siding/">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="imgpg"><img alt="" class="sectionImage" src="http://dev.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Siding-Landing-Page-Image-1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-row clearfix markets" id="fader">
      <div class="col two txtpg">
        <div class="col">
          <h3>Decking</h3>
          <p>Composite decking has come a long way in its brief two decade history, and Client Name has had a front row seat for the entire ride. What began as product to simply utilize scrap wood and shrink wrap that would have otherwise ended up in a land fill, has evolved into a highly engineered, luxury residential construction product.</p><a class="moreBtn" href="/markets/exterior-construction-outdoor-durable-products/decking/">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="imgpg"><img alt="" class="sectionImage" src="http://dev.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Decking-Landing-Page-Image.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="headerBanner"><img src="http://dev.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Exterior-Constuction_Parallax-2.jpg"></div>
  <div class="wrapper-body innerPage">
    <div class="wrap clearfix">
      <div class="col-row clearfix markets" id="fader">
        <div class="col two txtpg">
          <div class="col">
            <h3>Roofing</h3>
            <p>When it comes to roofing, we’ve got you covered.</p>
            <p>In commercial applications, we’ve been making color concentrates for outdoor durable films for over half a century, bringing extensive knowledge and experience to the table. Whether it’s for PVC, TPO, or any other polymer, you can rely on Client Name to maximize the performance and aesthetics of your film.</p><a class="moreBtn" href="/markets/exterior-construction-outdoor-durable-products/roofing/">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imgpg"><img alt="" class="sectionImage" src="http://dev.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Roofing_Landing-Page-Image.jpg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-row clearfix markets" id="fader">
        <div class="col two txtpg">
          <div class="col">
            <h3>Synthetic Turf</h3>
            <p>Artificial, or synthetic, turf is a surface of synthetic fibers made to look like natural grass. Because of recent aesthetic and performance improvements, it is now being used on residential and commercial lawns as well. Artificial turf performs well in heavy foot traffic areas and eliminates the need for irrigation or trimming, cutting down on maintenance and costs.</p><a class="moreBtn" href="/markets/exterior-construction-outdoor-durable-products/synthetic-turf/">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imgpg"><img alt="" class="sectionImage" src="http://dev.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Synthetic-Turf_Landing-Page-Image.jpg"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is JS I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.wrapper-body').prop('id', function (i, v) {
return v === '' || 'undefined' === typeof v ? 'new_added_id_' + 
String.fromCharCode(97 + i) : v;
});
    });
```

Comment: Please show a method or two that you've tried, and explain more than "none work".  What does / does not work?  You've tagged jQuery - is that really the way you want to go? Would a PHP solution work / be better?

Comment: You have **four** `id="fader"` on a single page. Do you know the purpose of IDs? And what are classes used for?

Comment: Also, instead of using `id="String.fromCharCode(97 + i)"` why don't you simply assign/concatenate the index number?

Comment: The id fader is dynamically added, trying to use js to change the id name

Comment: @JasonSprague What Roko C. Buljan was trying to get across is that YOU CANNOT USE ID's MORE THAN ONCE. You need to fix that before you move forward.

Comment: @Aaron Eveleth I know that already, I added the id for testing a single element and it works, however, it won't work as it is right now so what I'm asking is there a way to change the id from  "fader" to "fader1" "fader2" etc with js

Comment: @JasonSprague The problem is, ID's reference a single element, so you can't even loop through them to append a counter to the id. You need to add the same class to every element that has the id `fader`. Then loop through those elements. Using the `.each` function, I think the first parameter represents index, so you can update your id attribute to equal your id plus the index.

Comment: But if you are doing that, you might as well just fix this on the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Add an incremental counter so that you get #fader_1, #fader_2, #fader_3, and so on.

```
if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):
$i = 0;
while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();
$i++;
echo '<div id="fader_.'$i'.">';
the_sub_field('sub_field_name');
echo '</div>';
endwhile;
else :
// no rows found
endif;
```

Comment: Was missing  echo '<div id="fader_.'$i'.">'; in my php when i initially tried it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Goodluck with the rest of your site.